# phpmyadmin direct url access (post method)

Tags: phpmyadmin

I'm trying to access phpmyadmin using the url post method.

www.example.com/phpmyadmin/?pma_username=####&pma_password=####

But nothing happens, is phpmyadmin somehow blocking direct access through url? Or am i using the wrong post variables?

Here a piece of the untouched phpmyadmin index.php login form.

```
    <!-- Login form -->
<form method="post" id="login_form" action="index.php" name="login_form" class="disableAjax login hide js-show">
    <fieldset>
    <legend><input type="hidden" name="set_session" value="123" />Log in<a href="./doc/html/index.html" target="documentation"><img src="themes/dot.gif" title="Documentation" alt="Documentation" class="icon ic_b_help" /></a></legend><div class="item">
            <label for="input_username">Username:</label>
            <input type="text" name="pma_username" id="input_username" value="" size="24" class="textfield"/>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <label for="input_password">Password:</label>
            <input type="password" name="pma_password" id="input_password" value="" size="24" class="textfield" />
        </div>    <input type="hidden" name="server" value="1" /></fieldset><fieldset class="tblFooters"><input value="Go" type="submit" id="input_go" /><input type="hidden" name="target" value="index.php" /><input type="hidden" name="token" value="123" /></fieldset>
```

Comment: It is not clear how you are trying to access this page.... Is it using the browser? Is it using some other web client?  For what is worth passing parameters in the query string are NOT POST parameters... Please read about Query String parameters and the differences between POST and GET

Comment: It's through the browser. 
I have managed to login using the url with cpanel php post variables but when I try it on phpmyadmin with the variables I got from the source code it just does nothing.

Comment: probably required the request to be sent via HTTP POST....  Not HTTP GET

Answer (score 1):

Specifying parameters as part of the URL, as in `www.example.com/phpmyadmin/?pma_username=####&pma_password=####`, is actually a GET query, not POST (POST uses form values from on a web page rather than the URL query string).

The format you're trying to use is somewhat old and was removed in phpMyAdmin 4.9.0 due to [security concerns](https://www.phpmyadmin.net/security/PMASA-2019-4/). You can [still specify](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/faq.html#faq4-8) the server, database, table, and target page; however the username and password options are removed.

For similar functionality, you may be able to come up with a solution involving auth_type config (which hardcodes the username and password in to the configuration directive and therefore requires you to configure some other authentication means, such as HTTP BASIC through your web server) or auth_type signon (which requires implementing your own authentication script, examples are in the documentation). You may be able to come up with a redirection form based on passing actual POST values back to the logon page, but I'm not sure offhand if that would work due to security measures in place.

Basically, sorry, this feature is gone and unlikely to return.